# JW flv player IE doesn't work

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, jwplayer

Hey I've embedded JW flv player in my website. and it works perfect in chrome and firefox. But in all IE version it won't show up :S.

What's wrong with my code ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/flash/swfobject.js"></script> 
<br />
<div id="player" style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;">This text will be replaced</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('/flash/player-viral.swf','mpl','100%','180','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=http://{NAAM}.flv&image=http://{NAAM}.jpg&controlbar=none&dock=false');
so.write('player');</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am milind kansagara working in a project. I have used jwplayer 
for displaying a youtube video that has been uploaded in youtube. I have put following code in my page

Regards,
Milind Kansagara
http://milindkansagara1984.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code very little just took out the style. Please check the url http://{NAAM}.flv as this is not a valid url. Please add the correct urls and it should work.

This text will be replaced


var so = new SWFObject('/flash/player-viral.swf','mpl','100%','180','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=http://{NAAM}.flv&image=http://{NAAM}.jpg&controlbar=none&dock=false');
so.write('player');

Comment: Vice2doom: have you found a fix?